# Can't upload larger zip archive to CWP7

Tags: hosting, vps, centos-web-panel

I've setup VPS (webserver) on Centos 7 (Centos Web Panel 7) and I can't upload larger .zip archive (smaller archive works). 
When uploading, it completes but the .zip archive vanishes. 
Same results from root login and user panel login.

This is what I have:
PHP Version 7.3.6
Zip   enabled
Zip version   1.15.4
Libzip headers version   1.5.1
Libzip library version   1.5.1

I am trying to upload 120MB zip archive containing 46000 files.
What is the problem here?
Thanks

I've only changed this in my global php.ini:

```
upload_max_filesize = 2000M
max_file_uploads = 100000
```

Comment: same issue here, did you resolve it?